# Filter dictionary in pyspark with key names

Tags: sql, dictionary, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Given a dictionary like column in a dataset, I want to grab the value from a key given that the value from another key is satisfied.

Example:
Say I have a column 'statistics' in a dataset, where each data row looks as:

```
array
0: {"hair": "black", "eye": "white", "metric": "feet"}
1: {"hair": "blue", "eye": "white", "metric": "m"}
2: {"hair": "red", "eye": "brown", "metric": "feet"}
3: {"hair": "yellow", "eye": "white", "metric": "cm"}
```

I want to get the value of 'eye' whenever hair is 'black'

I tried:

```
select
statistics.eye("*").filter(statistics.hair, x -> x == 'black')
from arrayData
```

but it gives an error and I'm unable to grab the value for eye, please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out without having to first convert to a dataframe.

The aggregate command allows you to grab the value from a key given that the value from another key is satisfied. For this instance, the command below will suffice:

```
select 
aggregate(statistics,"",(agg,item)->concat(agg,CASE WHEN item.hair == 'black' THEN item.eye ELSE "" END)) as EyeColor
from arrayData
```

For more details on how to use this function, see [here](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/data-transformation/higher-order-lambda-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to dataframe and read it .. You can also register this as temptable and read as sql

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df=sc.parallelize([{"hair": "black", "eye": "white", "metric": "feet"},{"hair": "blue", "eye": "white", "metric": "m"},{"hair": "red", "eye": "brown", "metric": "feet"},{"hair": "yellow", "eye": "white", "metric": "cm"}]).toDF()
>>> df.show()
+-----+------+------+
|  eye|  hair|metric|
+-----+------+------+
|white| black|  feet|
|white|  blue|     m|
|brown|   red|  feet|
|white|yellow|    cm|
+-----+------+------+
>>> df.filter(F.col("hair") == 'black').show()
+-----+-----+------+
|  eye| hair|metric|
+-----+-----+------+
|white|black|  feet|
+-----+-----+------+
df.createOrReplaceTempView("data")
spark.sql("select * from data where hair ='black'")
```